# How to fix nlohmann type error when trying to parse json into map?

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I've been working with json files using c++ and I came across `nlohmann json parser`. I am trying to parse the json into a map of char and string vector, but I keep getting the same error:
`[type_error.302] type must be array but is object`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<char, std::vector<std::string>> wordList;
    std::ifstream file("wordlist.json");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open wordlist.json");
    }

    json data;
    file >> data;
    wordList = data.get<decltype(wordList)>();
}
```

and this is the json example I used

```json
{
    "a": ["apple", "apricot"],
    "b": ["banana", "blueberry"],
    "c": ["cherry", "cranberry"]
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this code

Comment: `"a"` is not `char`, use `std::string` for map keys.

Comment: What I might suggest, fill the map with values, then print out the JSON using the `dump` function, and see what format it's actually expecting. Basically, you're giving it a JSON object, but what it's actually expecting is a JSON array with objects in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the keys in your wordlist.json only has one character, they are still string. So the solution is to change this line from:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<char, std::vector<std::string>> wordList;
```

To:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> wordList;
```